# Zero length (0 kb) minor version check in

Tags: 2010

We have an very rare issue where a user performs a minor check in for a document from Microsoft Word, and the commit is made, but with a 0KB file size.

[image: Version History]

There's the v0.33 commit which was empty and is the root cause, the user tried to recover the document with the v0.34, and finally they reverted back to v0.32 and did a minor commit to restore the document to a last known-good condition.

This is on SharePoint 2010, and here's the build information.

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
14     0      6117   5002
```

The logs show the SOAP call for the document being committed using CsiSrvExe, and the incremental saves from the client, but I see nothing else indicating a root cause.

---

```
10/29/2014 15:57:59.17  CsiSrvExe.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1434)    0x1544  SharePoint Foundation   Client File Access  7wqy    Medium  ttidLogCellStg      Unlimited quota specified for a server QueryChanges request.    0191ecb6-b5e6-493b-86c1-2ce73517d983
10/29/2014 15:57:59.22  CsiSrvExe.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1434)    0x1544  SharePoint Foundation   Client File Access  7wqy    Medium  ttidLogCellStg      Unlimited quota specified for a server QueryChanges request.    0191ecb6-b5e6-493b-86c1-2ce73517d983
10/29/2014 15:57:59.22  CsiSrvExe.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1434)    0x1544  SharePoint Foundation   Client File Access  7wqy    Medium  ttidLogCellStg      Unlimited quota specified for a server QueryChanges request.    0191ecb6-b5e6-493b-86c1-2ce73517d983
10/29/2014 15:57:59.36  CsiSrvExe.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1434)    0x1544  SharePoint Foundation   Client File Access  7wqy    Medium  ttidLogCellStg      Unlimited quota specified for a server QueryChanges request.    0191ecb6-b5e6-493b-86c1-2ce73517d983
10/29/2014 15:57:59.38  CsiSrvExe.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1434)    0x1544  SharePoint Foundation   Client File Access  7wqy    Medium  ttidLogWssCellStg   IServerStorageWriteTxn::Commit calling IStreamBridge::PutStreams with etag "{7389AA08-8CB0-45FA-884B-FEF47C221D12},159", last fragment 0    0191ecb6-b5e6-493b-86c1-2ce73517d983
10/29/2014 15:57:59.97  CsiSrvExe.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1434)    0x1544  SharePoint Foundation   Client File Access  7wqy    Medium  ttidLogWssCellStgConcise [Url: https://site.company.com/sites/collection/Folder/File.doc][User: DOMAIN\user][User-agent: GUID={1984108C-4B93-4EEB-B320-919432D6E593}, OfficeBuildNumber=14.0.7104.5000 requestVersion=12][StreamSizes: Request=1171317 bytes, Response=284 bytes][TotalRequestTime: 812msec][PartitionID: Default][Request: PutChanges **PFU Result=Success][cbOld=4481024][cbNew=4481536][cbOldFFM-C=16074][cbNewFFM-C=16230][cbOldFFM=57580][cbNewFFM=57502][Coalesce: Ran successfully in 750msec (ClientRequested, NonHotAwarePartition)]   0191ecb6-b5e6-493b-86c1-2ce73517d983
10/29/2014 15:58:01.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:https://site.company.com:443/sites/collection/_vti_bin/versions.asmx)    e9a2dec5-3b32-41b6-bf67-df63165d7c93
10/29/2014 15:58:01.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation   General fbv5    Medium  SoapAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetVersions    e9a2dec5-3b32-41b6-bf67-df63165d7c93
10/29/2014 15:58:01.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation   General fbv6    Medium  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Body> <GetVersions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> <fileName><![CDATA[Folder/File.doc]]></fileName> </GetVersions> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope> e9a2dec5-3b32-41b6-bf67-df63165d7c93
10/29/2014 15:58:01.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/collection  e9a2dec5-3b32-41b6-bf67-df63165d7c93
10/29/2014 15:58:02.05  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x18EC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:https://site.company.com:443/sites/collection/_vti_bin/versions.asmx)). Execution Time=73.9882   e9a2dec5-3b32-41b6-bf67-df63165d7c93
10/29/2014 15:58:11.92  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:https://site.company.com:443/sites/collection/_vti_bin/lists.asmx)   1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:11.92  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   General fbv5    Medium  SoapAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile    1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:11.92  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   General fbv6    Medium  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Body> <CheckInFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> <pageUrl>https://site.company.com/sites/collection/Folder/File.doc</pageUrl><comment>ES Finished edits</comment><CheckinType>0</CheckinType></CheckInFile> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>  1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:11.94  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/collection  1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:12.69  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=39.6835   1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:12.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Performance nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {1CD09823-E8CE-4AAD-BC4E-4F1A112F2B6E}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.   1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:12.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Performance nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {143D13A1-13B4-4CEC-AB45-D7DB93D9EE98}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.   1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:12.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Performance nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {6E8DE45D-9A6D-4457-9A6E-F90AC7B27285}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.   1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:12.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Performance nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {E6E382DD-5801-4A04-A2DA-C249F45F6B76}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.   1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:12.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Performance nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {21819D7F-0A4F-4FA9-B244-70953265C5EA}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.   1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
10/29/2014 15:58:12.99  w3wp.exe (CLIENT-WFE01P:0x1AC4) 0x1394  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:https://site.company.com:443/sites/collection/_vti_bin/lists.asmx)). Execution Time=1059.6127    1481de85-fcd9-4752-a8e4-17e30e9f8a6e
```

---

Comment: is this with one file or all files in a library or it is across the farm?

Comment: This is just one file, however I have been told that in the past once it happens to one file it's more likely to occur to that one again, so the issue may be based off contents of the document (overall size, uncompressed images, etc.). This document in particular is several hundred pages.

Comment: if it is with one file then may be file having some issues

Comment: My current working theory is that there's a disconnect during the check in process when it's staging changes, and when the CsiSrvExe expects the data to arrive it never does, so it ends up committing an empty file. I'm in the process of writing a PowerShell script that calls upon a macro to try to reproduce this with a large file.

Comment: ok, that is possible. what i am seeing may be at the backend(db level) some resource deadlock happen when this trancsaction was in process so may be it lost.

Comment: SQL deadlock is the other running theory. I'm going to throw these ideas at our test server next week and see what sticks. Thanks for the input!

Comment: please share the output so that community get benifit